# Python ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (234, 11) instead

Tags: python

```
x = disp_dummies.drop('hwy',axis=1).values
y = disp_dummies['hwy'].values

label_X = LabelEncoder()
X = label_X.fit_transform(x)
encoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = encoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

X_train, X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.4, random_state = 0)
```

ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (234, 11) instead.

I want to fit logistic regression where y is dependent variable, and x is independent variable. But while I'm using :
lr.fit(x,y)

Originally I was reshaping the data by using
y=y.reshape(-1,1)
however I've removed the reshaping

Comment: What is the output of the dataset? It should be a single column right? That's what I am trying to explain in my answer.

Comment: Well, *what is `y`!?* The error message tells you it's incorrect, but if you don't tell us what is *is*, we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

The function `train_test_split` expects the second argument `y` as a *One dimensional* array.
The array `y` should contain the list of expected outputs.
But the array `y` in your case is a 2D array containing `11` elements corresponding to each element in the first dimension.
The array `y` in your case is like

````
y = [
[. . . . . . . . . . .]
[. . . . . . . . . . .]
.
.
.
.
[. . . . . . . . . . .]
[. . . . . . . . . . .]
]```
````